# Best practices for securing a public Java Spring-Boot web app

Tags: rest, spring-boot, security, web-applications

I've got a public Java web app created with Spring Boot. I'm ready to release it to production and wanted to get some tips on making sure that it is as secure as possible.

It is basically a search engine that uses Apache Lucene in the backed and a lot of javascript in the front end. I am planning on deploying it to Amazon Web Services, while using my local machine as a backup/test enviroment.

Users can search and browse data. The frontend calls REST endpoints using Javascripts XMLHttpRequest to query the backend for content and then displays it to the user.

The app is completely public and there is no user authentication as of yet.

The app also persists user requests to a database for tracking purposes.

Here's what I've done so far to secure it:

- Make sure that the REST endpoints fully verify that the parameters given to them in the requests are valid.

What I plan on doing:

- Using HTTPS.
- Verifying that any put request or url requests have a reasonable size.

What I am considering adding:

- Limiting the number of requests a  user can make in a given time period. (not sure if Spring-Boot already has a facility to do this, or I should implement this myself)
- Use some kind of API key scheme to make sure that my endpoints are only accessed by my front end. (not sure if this is effective and don't yet know how to do this).

Is there anything else that I should consider doing? Do the things I listed above make sense?

Would greatly appreciate any tips on this.

Comment: To limit your endpoints to be reached only by your frontend, I would suggest looking at [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). To look up it's Spring implementation and an example, see [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/). In any case, Spring comes with a fully equipped security framework: [Spring Security](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security).

Comment: Your question is a little too broad for this site. I am voting to close it as such.